# Как на Kaggle решить проблему с Your notebook tried to allocate more memory than is available. Ih has restarted

Tags: python, pandas, kaggle

Пробую обучать модель на Kaggle. Для генерации признаков использую следующий код

```
import itertools

def itr_combinations_new_features(data):
    
    tmp_df = data.copy()
    
    old_columns = [item for item in tmp_df.columns.tolist() if item != 'rating']
    
    tmp_df_sum_2 = [(pd.Series(tmp_df.loc[:,list(i)].sum(axis=1),\
            name='_sum2_'.join(tmp_df.loc[:,list(i)].columns))) for i in list(itertools.combinations(old_columns,2))]
    
    tmp_df_sum_3 = [(pd.Series(tmp_df.loc[:,list(i)].sum(axis=1),\
            name='_sum3_'.join(tmp_df.loc[:,list(i)].columns))) for i in list(itertools.combinations(old_columns,3))]
    
    tmp_df_multiplication = [(pd.Series(tmp_df.loc[:,i[0]]*tmp_df.loc[:,i[1]],\
            name='_mult_'.join(tmp_df.loc[:,list(i)].columns))) for i in list(itertools.combinations(old_columns,2))]
    
   
    df_sum_2 = pd.DataFrame(tmp_df_sum_2).T  
    
    df_sum_3 = pd.DataFrame(tmp_df_sum_3).T  
    
    df_multiplication = pd.DataFrame(tmp_df_multiplication).T  
   
    data = pd.concat([data, df_sum_2, df_sum_3, df_multiplication], axis=1, sort=False)         
 
    
    return data
```

В тренировочного датасета размер около 800 тыс строк и 7 признаков (колонок). Запускаю процесс и он сразу нагружает CPU Kaggle из-за чего вываливается "Your notebook tried to allocate more memory than is available. Ih has restarted."

Признаков немного в датасете, поэтому приходится генерировать их автоматически.

Как решить проблему?

Может код не оптимален? Или можно как-то ограничить нагрузку на CPU?

Comment: Ну, если каждый признак с каждым комбинировать, у вас всё очень быстро вырастет. Попробуйте для начала сразу печатать размеры получающихся датасетов (`.shape`) подозреваю, что там получается очень много. Если памяти не сильно нехватает, можно попробовать понизить размер данных до минимально возможных, функции для этого на каггле много раз приводили. Ну, грубо говоря - перевести все данные в `np.float16`, например. И после этого уже комбинировать столбцы. Но в целом это какой-то странный подход - нужно сначала смотреть на данные (статистика, графики), а потом уже что-то с ними делать пытаться.

Comment: Да уже неделю с данными работаю. Перепробовал разные модели и статистики. Не хватает признаков. Приходится вытягивать. Классический вариант - перемножение 2, 3 признаков между собой - дают неплохие результаты не Кегле. Спасибо за идею относительно уменьшения размера данных

Comment: Ну или можно постепенно такие признаки добавлять и проверять. Нагенерить сколько-то, посмотреть, какие из них полезные, ещё нагенерить, опять отобрать... Методы отбора признаков тоже есть всякие разные. Конечно, хорошо бы сразу все проверять, но не всегда есть такая возможность.

Comment: Ах да, забыл самое главное - сэмплирование! Не обязательно работать сразу со всеми 800 тыс. строк, можно взять только часть данных (какую - надо пробовать) и отбирать признаки на этой части. А потом уже, когда отберёте нужные признаки - сгенерить их для всего датасета. Для уверенности можно проделать весь процесс, начиная с сэмплирования, несколько раз. Каждый раз могут отбираться в итоге несколько разные признаки, можно потом взять их объединение, например. Или наоборот пересечение. Смотря насколько у вас сильно признаки отбрасываться будут при отборе. В общем, процесс это творческий.